# Server/Client classes with two dimensional array (Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am EXTREMELY new to Java and completely lost on the concept of ARRAYS.  I need to create a "World" class to display a two dimensional array that is user specified in size, using a constructor that accepts two values [rows] and [columns] with a character (Lets say "P") located in the array.  A separate "Driver" class will hold the main method.  Other methods (moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, and moveRight) need to be created to move the character around inside the array.  There needs to be a fifth method to display the world array.  I currently have the following code, but nothing is working so I got rid of it.  even this code itself won't compile - says "identifier expected before the parenthesis of my second println.  I have no idea why this won't go any further.  This is the only place I have to seek help since the college offers no tutors for Java, youtube videos are extremely vague and use terminology I do not know, library books I've checked out don't show me the actual code needed to perform these tasks, and the class textbook shows code close, but not quite what is needed.  and since I'm extremely new to Java, my last questions garnered me the threat of losing the ability to post on this site, so that would take away my only recourse for help if this is also dubbed inferior.  I do not know what to do at this point.

```
import java.util.*;
public class World
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(array);
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of row: ");
    private int crow = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
    private int ccol = input.nextInt();
    private String[][] array = newString[crow][ccol];   

    public int displayWorld()
    {

    }
    public int moveUp()
    {

    }
    public int moveDown()
    {

    }
    public int moveLeft()
    {

    }
    public int moveRight()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: You should provide that code here which you coded on your own. Don't get frustrated, the community is here for help.

Comment: I am voting to close as "too broad". You are asking about coding a client/server application, and this is a task that is a bit complicated, but there seems to be many fundamental Java concepts that you don't know yet. You need to start with something simpler, and work your way up to more complex programs. Also, you can expect to just find exactly the code you need. You will have to learn the principles, and then create that code yourself. If programming was just about finding the right code to copy, it would be much easier, but unfortunately it is not often you can do that.

Comment: Remove the `}` after your `System.out.println(array);`. It indicates the end of the main method and the remaining code isn't in any method, resulting in an error. You should also read the basic tutorials [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), otherwise you won't get anywhere. Programming is hard, so don't believe you can just cheat your way through it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorials.  I'll check into those and see if they can help me understand this better.  As far as fundamental stuff, we are currently on Chapter 9, and the only issues I've had are when they introduced arrays in Chapter 7.  since then, I have been lost and have sought help from the instructor as well as other students on the class forums to no avail.

Comment: I think the piece you're not aware of right now is that a class is made up of methods. The first line of a method describes it, and then the `{` starts it, and the `}` ends it. So any procedural code outside of a method won't compile. Your World class needs to define the methods to manipulate the array, which you've started, but it needs to be constructed from Driver as I understand your project. Look up constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Compling problems-> use an IDE (eclipse netbeans idea jdeveloper ...) for developing java applications.

Here you have part of one solution, since you are  learning, play with this code before implementing the rest of methods.

Regarding java learning, there are plenty of good tutorials by searching on google.

```
import java.util.*;

public class World{
    private static final String P="P";
    private String[][] array;

    public World(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of row: ");
        int crow = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns: ");
        int ccol = input.nextInt();
        array = new String[crow][ccol]; 
        array[0][0]=P;
    }


    public void displayWorld(){
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void moveUp(){

    }

    public void moveDown(){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
                if ((array[i][j])!=null){
                    if (i<array.length-1){
                        array[i][j]=null;
                        array[i+1][j]=P;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveLeft(){

    }

    public void moveRight(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        World world=new World();
        world.displayWorld();
        world.moveDown();
        world.displayWorld();

    }
}
```